# SQL select from column where column equals table variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, select

I'm a serious SQL noob so any help is appreciated.  I'm having a hard time even explaining what I'm trying to do so I'll lay out what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @UserIDInt table (ID int);

INSERT into @UserIDInt
    SELECT UserId 
    FROM [LcsCDR].[dbo].[Users]
    WHERE [LcsCDR].[dbo].[Users].[UserUri] LIKE '%example';

SELECT * 
FROM [LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetails]
WHERE [LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetails].[User1Id] = @UserIDInt;


"DECLARE @UserIDInt table (ID int);"
```

This creates my variable with a column called "ID"

```
INSERT into @UserIDInt
    SELECT UserId 
    FROM [LcsCDR].[dbo].[Users]
    WHERE [LcsCDR].[dbo].[Users].[UserUri] LIKE '%example';
```

This adds numeric values into the ID column based on whether or not the WHERE statement matched

```
SELECT * 
FROM [LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetails]
WHERE [LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetails].[User1Id] = @UserIDInt;
```

This is where I am lost. I am trying to return all rows from `[LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetails]` if the column `[LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetails].[User1Id]` matches anything in my variable. The problem (I think) I'm having is that SQL can't look within the variable's column to find multiple values. Basically, the ID column in my variable @UserIDInt will contain a bunch of numeric values.

How do I perform the final SELECT statement and have SQL return all results if `[LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetails].[User1Id]` matches anything within my `@UserIDInt.ID` column?

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Apologies if I explained it badly. Not sure how else to ask the question :)

Comment: Hint : `Exists`

Comment: You have an answer, but I'll add another comment. DON'T create a temp table or table variable at all. Just use the same strategy as @SqlZim uses but query the real source table directly. There is generally no advantage to dumping a resultset into a temp table if it only serves to filter the resultset of the query that follows. Do not follow design patterns blindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `inner join`:

```
select sd.*
from [lcscdr].[dbo].[sessiondetails] sd 
  inner join @useridint i
    on i.id = sd.user1id;
```

or using `exists()`:

```
select sd.*
from [lcscdr].[dbo].[sessiondetails] sd 
where exists (
  select 1 
  from @useridint i
  where i.id = sd.user1id
  );
```

or using `in()`:

```
select sd.*
from [lcscdr].[dbo].[sessiondetails] sd 
where sd.user1id in (
  select id
  from @useridint i
  );
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UVCB28056

Comment: Thanks for the response!  However, all the above seem to return no results, even though I have confirmed that data is being added to the table variable I created.  I'm simply replacing my final SELECT statement with yours, and it all seems to run just fine (just returns no results).

Comment: @Grayson then the ID's in your table variable aren't present in your dataset, likely because of some other limiting factor (like other items in the where clause)

Comment: If I run a "SELECT * FROM @UserIDInt;" it definitely returns two rows with numbers present in both rows.  Wouldn't that indicate that there is data present in my variable?

EDIT: I fixed it; turns out I'm an idiot and was looking for the wrong info.  Your script was absolutely correct.  Thanks a bunch for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM [lcscdr].[dbo].[sessiondetails] T1 WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM @useridint T2
  WHERE T2.id = T1.user1id
  );
```